# Stacked Bar Chart with Percentages Using Character Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, charts

Say I have this data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " name1 name2
jim bob
jim bob
jim tom
jim sue
jim other
sue bob
sue tom
sue jim
bob bob
bob jim
bob bob
bob sue
bob jim
bob other
bob other",sep = "",header = TRUE)
```

How can I make a stacked bar chart using ggplot2? I would like `name1` to be on the x-axis, with the percentage of each `name2` on the y-axis. So, for `jim`, it would have `bob` be .4, `tom` be .2, `sue` be .2, and `other` be .2.

Comment: Oops, good catch. I thought the denominator was 6, when it was 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can calculate the ratio of each `name2` in `name1` and plot them using `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat %>%
  group_by(name1, name2) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name1, n,  fill = name2, label = round(n, 2)) +
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick follow-up if that's OK. How would I change the position of one category (`other`) in the y-axis so that it always appears at, say, the top? Or arrange the order of the x categories (so maybe `sue` is first)?

Comment: @bill999 you could arrange the factor levels based on the order of your choice. So start with `dat %>%
  mutate(name2 = factor(name2, levels = c("other", setdiff(levels(name2), "other")))) %>%
  group_by(name1, name2)......` so "other" is always on top. Or `dat %>%
  mutate(name1 = factor(name1, levels = c("sue", setdiff(levels(name1), "sue")))) %>%
  group_by(name1, name2).......` so that "sue" is the first.

Comment: Very helpful. Much appreciated!